# Clear controls after file download in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation, itext

I have a web page having grid control and treeview. The main functionality is to download forms based on the selection from tree and grid. So it works fine and what I want to do is, to clear the selection after pdf download and unfortunately with my code it's not happening. I am generating pdf files using itextsharp. My code is as follows

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
foreach (var file in filesToInclude)
{
    try
    {
        PdfReader ps = new PdfReader(file);
        PdfStamper pdf = new PdfStamper(ps, ms);//2
        pdf.Close();//4
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();//5
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();//6
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";//7
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Session["Form_Name"]);//8
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());//9
        ms.Flush();
        clearcontrols();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the code in `finally` block so it always clears it even if there is an exception. Also, having an empty catch block is not a good practice. You are suppressing the exception instead of handling it.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
foreach (var file in filesToInclude)
{
    try
    {
        PdfReader ps = new PdfReader(file);
        PdfStamper pdf = new PdfStamper(ps, ms);//2
        pdf.Close();//4
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();//5
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();//6
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";//7
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Session["Form_Name"]);//8
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());//9
        ms.Flush();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HandleException(); // Write code to handle exception 
    }
    finally
    {
         clearcontrols();
    }
}
```

Comment: i put ajax rad ajax manager in page and loading panel. So now the downlaod process itself not working, anybody knows this problem?